# Using numpy.random.choice w/o replacement to draw items from a bag

Tags: python, numpy

I'm still quite new to python, and am working through a problem for class. I feel like I'm really close to the solution, but my numbers still aren't coming out how I would expect from probability.

In the problem, we have a bag with two chips inside. We know one of the chips is white, and the other is either black or white. These conditions are true each time we play the game.

In the game, we've drawn one chip out of the bag and it was white.  The problem is to write a function that approximates the probability of drawing two white chips out of the bag. The argument of the function is the number of times we play the game.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
def prob_two_whites(num):
    counter = 0     #counts the number of iterations or games played
    first_white = 0     #counts how many times the first pull was white
    double_white = 0    #counts how many times the second pull was white, if the first was also white
    while counter < num:    #runs a game until total number of games is reached
        chip_1 = "white"    #this is the chip we know is white
        chip_2 = np.random.choice(["white","black"])    #chip two has an equal chance of being white or black for each game
        result = np.random.choice([chip_1, chip_2], 2, replace = False)   #drawing both chips without replacement
        if result[0] == "white":    #if the first chip pulled is white
            first_white += 1        # add one to the first white
            if result[1] == "white":    #if the second pull was white, given the first was also white
                double_white += 1       # add one to double_white
        counter +=1          #add one to the counter
    return (float(double_white)/float(first_white)) / (float(first_white)/float(counter))
```

Effectively, the result should be approximately 66.66%

Probabilistically, the chance of the first pull being white is 75%.  Once the first white is pulled, there's approximately a 50% chance of the second pull being white.

When I look at the distinct counts of first_white and double_white, the first_white numbers appear to be tallying as they should (about 75% of total count), but my double_white counts are consistently too high. I feel like my code is pretty straight-forward, but somehow it seems I'm counting double-whites more than I should.

Any help anyone could provide would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you should divide double_white by counter not first_white. `return (float(double_white) / float(counter)) / (float(first_white)/float(counter))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the issue is not with any of the random number generation or the counting, but with your probability computation at the end.

The conditional probability of getting two white results given that the first result was white is `double_white / first_white` (simply divide the two counts). That's a simplified form of the ratio of their independent probabilities: `(double_white / count) / (first_white / count)` (note that `count` can be canceled out)

Normally Bayes' law would say there needs to be an extra term in the numerator when dividing those probabilities or counts. But as it happens, the extra term is the reversed conditional probability (the probability the first chip was white if both of them are white) which is 100% (or `1`). Multiplying by `1` doesn't do anything so it can be left out of the calculation.

I've omitted all the `float` calls above, both for clarity, and because they really shouldn't be necessary. If you're using Python 3, division between two integers will generate a `float` result by default (you can explicitly request integer division by using the `//` floor division operator). If you're still stuck using Python 2, you can get the Python 3 behavior if you put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file (I strongly recommend it!).

Comment: Thanks!  It makes a lot more sense when you mention cancelling out the "count" from the the ratio.  It's good to know that my code was working (more or less) as intended.  I appreciate the help!